# Using LDAPSEARCH to return all Groups and OU's in an Active Directory domain

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

What would the correct syntax be, using ldapsearch, to return all Groups\OU's and their nested Groups\OU's in an AD domain?
I am trying to query a Windows AD DC from a Linux Box and need to have this result returned to the Linux machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All groups in the DOMAIN would be:

```
(objectClass=group)
```

All groups and OUs would be:

```
(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=Group))
```

Not sure what Groups\OU's implies.

-jim

Answer (score 0):

For a full ldapsearch example:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap://<host IP or NAME> -D <admin dn> -b <base dn> -s sub -w <admin dn pass> "(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=Group))"
```